# Set "sideload apps" from Windows 10 powershell (Update & Security > For developers)

Tags: powershell, windows-store-apps, windows-10, updates, sideloading

Is it possible to set the "Update & Security > For developers" attribute "Sideload apps" from a powershell script on Windows 10 Anniversary (just plain "old" Win10)?

Answer (score 7):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#which-settings-should-i-choose-sideload-apps-or-developer-mode:

Run PowerShell with administrator privileges.
To enable sideloading, run this command:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowAllTrustedApps" /d "1"
```

To enable developer mode, run this command:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "1"
```

Comment: Works like a charm. 1000 x Thx